# C language : passing info through a File .csv to a struct using linked list

Tags: c, csv

I'm having some troubles passing the information of a .csv file to a struct using linked lists...

The file is like:

```
1,3.234,hello,f
3,4.2432,worldkind,o
.
.
.
```

My C Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 50
typedef struct TP
{
    int key;
    //data
    int atomnum;
    float massnum;
    char nome[MAX+1];
    char sym[MAX+1];
    struct tableper *nseg;
    struct tableper *nant;
}tp;

tp* putmemory(tp *dbase1) //function to put data to struct
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char *token,ch,temp[MAX];
    int *tokenint,i,aux[MAX],in=-1,flag=0;
    char BUFFER[MAX],*aux2;
    tp *nv;

    if ((fp1 = fopen("TabelaPeriodica.csv","r")) == NULL)
        printf("File could not be opened \n");

    while(!feof(fp1))
    {
        while((ch=fgetc(fp1)) != '\r') 
        {
            temp[++in]=ch;
            if(ch == ',')
            {
                nv->key = ++i;
                token = strtok(temp[++i],",");
                nv->atomnum = token;
                token = strtok(NULL,",");
                nv->massnum = atof(token);
                token = strtok(NULL,",");
                strcpy(nv->nome,token);
                token = strtok(NULL,",");
                strcpy(nv->sym,token);
                free(nv);
            }       
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    tp *dbase1;
    putmemory(dbase1);
    return 0;
}
```

My problems are:

1. pass a vector of chars to a vector of string
2. read each line and save in struct
3. each iteration save nv(new_node) to struct using linked list

Comment: `while((ch=fgetc(fp1)) != '\r')` only works on Windows. I suggest you replace it with `while((ch=fgetc(fp1)) != '\n')` which works just as well on Windows and on all other Operating Systems.

Comment: what's a `struct tableper`? What part of this is supposed to be linked-list based?

Comment: my bad... tableper=tb [NAME OF STRUCT] sorry....humm i didn't knew about that, really thanks. i already think that it was really weird, cuz iḿ using linux and '\r' didn work as well..

Answer (score 1):

one of the many issues I spot is that you never allocate memory for `nv`...
Also I would use `fgets` to read a whole line and then use `strtok` on it

again, you have to allocate `nv`, and then set `dbase1` to it, so you build up a linked list

Comment: i prefer fgets too, but what i use on integer parameter of it ?

Comment: first param is pointer to buffer, second param is the size of this bufffer which should corresponds to the max line length that shoul dbe read

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for `nv`.

In your current code, `nv` is an uninitialized pointer. You can't use it just like that.

*Also you have a `free(nv)` in your code and no corresponding `nv = malloc(sizeof *nv);` or similar*

Comment: i already fix that. tell me if this is right:

while(fgets(temp,sizeof(temp),fp1) != NULL)
   nv =(tp*) malloc (sizeof(tp));
 //make strtok for each var of struct
 if(dbase1 == NULL)
 dbase1 = nv;
 else
 void insert_at_end()
 {
 printf("\nEnter your element in the linked list :");
 scanf("%d",&info);
 temp=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));  
 temp->num=info;
 temp->next=NULL;
 temp->prev=NULL;
 if(head==NULL)                      
 {
 head=temp;
 first=temp;
 last=temp;
 }
 else
 {
 while(dbase1->next!=NULL)
 {
 dbase1 = dbase1->next;
 }
 dbase1 ->next=nv;
 nv->prev=dbase1;
 nv->next=NULL;
 }
 }

Comment: Code in the comments area is totally unreadable. Please edit your question with the code changes. One thing I can see in your code is a function definition: `void insert_at_end() { /* ... */ }` out of place. In C you cannot have function defined inside other functions.